# When exporting function met with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am importing a library in javascript and I am writing a JS function that calls the library. Afterwhich I would like to export this JS file over to my TS component.ts file.

Under the assets/js folder, I have demo.js and demo.d.ts

In [demo.js]:

```
export function myMethod(){
 var jrQrcode = require('jr-qrcode');
 var imgBase64 = jrQrcode.getQrBase64('hello world');
 return imgBase64;
}
```

In [demo.d.ts]:

```
export declare function myMethod();
```

In [app.component.ts]:

```
import { myMethod } from 'src/assets/js/demo';
```

Actually the code runs and works well, but I'm having this error that says: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export" . This error points to the "demo.js" file, the first export functio line.

Could someone help me with this please?